# Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ chapter 4 drill step 6 : General question about numeric range

Tags: c++

I want to prompt the user for some double, then store the smallest and largest value and then prints a text. This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{       
    double min = 1000000000; // Here is my issue !
    double max = -100000000; // Here is my issue !
    for (double input; cin >> input;)
    {
        if (input == '|')
            return 0;
        else if (input < min)
        {
            min = input;
            cout << "The smallest so far\n";
        }
        else if (input > max)
        {
            max = input;
            cout << "The largest so far\n";
        }
        else
            cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

So my code is working fine and doing what I want, but I have a question about the way to handle the double min and max.
I must give them a value to get my program working, but giving them a value inpact the user. If I don't set them high or low enough the user might input value that don't trigger the program.
So I set them up at arbitrary high/low number. 
But I wonder if there is a better solution for this.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/

Comment: Can you update the title of the question to better reflect the actual question? :)

Comment: How can a `double` number be equal to a character?  Example: `(input == '|')`?  Have you tested this?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews : It might seems counter intuitive but it's working for sure. Feel free to test it. The idea is when you input it it trigger the retun 0 and close the program. Working on virtual studio console and c++ shell.

Comment: @Kikizork actually my precedent comment was wrong `code`(input == '|') don't do anything at this point. Any not double input close the program. But it's a step by step exercice and later we add an unit so the format is : double unit(string). So we use this part of the code to close the program and before to print things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I don't set them high or low enough the user might input value that don't trigger the program.

Correct.

> But I wonder if there is a better solution for this.

There is!

`1000000000` may indeed be not enough. You might be interested in [numeric limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max). What you want is:

```
double min = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
double max = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();
```

which will set both values to the greatest and smallest representable `double`, respectively.

Don't forget to `#include <limits>`.

Comment: Attention, `min()` somewhat surprisingly returns the minimal *positive* representable number, what the OP is looking for is `lowest()`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest

Comment: How about `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()`?

Answer (score 3):

I came too late to answer the question, however I wanted to draw your attention on that in your case you must use `lowest()` and **not** `min()`

```
double min = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
double max = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();  // <-- Attention, not min
```

using `min()` instead of `lowest()` is a common error (yes the name is misleading)

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest):

> `lowest()` [static] (C++11) returns the **lowest** finite value of the given
>   type  (public static member function)
>
> `min()` [static] returns the **smallest** finite value of the given type 
>   (public static member function)

```
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();
```

prints:

```
2.22507e-308    <-- min    : smallest value
-1.79769e+308   <-- lowest : is what you need in your case
```